# Assigning value to variable in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on an XSLT where there are two **foreach blocks**. say **Block1** and **Block2**

Based on the elements in for loop in Block1, I will be generating a variable which will be used in Block2.

The problem is with asigning value to variable in first block

**Case-1** **I define variable inside Block 1**, say var

- In this case I cannot reference variable var in second Block(i.e Block2), in gives me **variable out-of-scope error**.

**Case-2** **I define variable outside both Blocks,** say as a global variable.

- In this case I can refrence the variable **BUT** the change made to variable in Block1 is not reflected in Block2.

Comment: Right now, you are [asking about your solution rather than about the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Look at it from a different perspective: Explain what your input XML looks like and what your _goal_ is, the expected output. Show your attempted XSLT code to achieve that (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple: You cannot assign values to variables in XSLT, because as a functional language, part of the language design is specifically about not allowing this.

From you question it is not quite clear what you want to do. Maybe one way to solve your problem is to write "Block 2" as a function/template (depending on whether you're using 2.0 or 1.0), and call it from "Block 1" with a parameter that passes the value.

But without sharing a better description of what exactly you're doing, it is hard to help, other than saying that assigning variables simply is something that XSLT will not allow you to do.